# When I goto start up my discord bot, I get the error token is not defined

Tags: discord.js

**I've tried multiple fixes and I am unable to figure out what is wrong send help...**
The bot at the moment is supposed to run simple commands and hopefully sometime in the near future be an application bot

Index.js

```
const { Client, Collection } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({
    intents: 32767,
});
module.exports = client;

// Global Variables
client.commands = new Collection();
client.slashCommands = new Collection();
client.config = require("./config.json");

// Initializing the project
require("./handler")(client);

client.login(client.config.token);
```

config.json

```
{
    "token": "My discord bot token",
    "prefix": "!",
}
```

error

```
C:\Users\Hello\djs-base-handler\index.js:16
client.login(token);
             ^

ReferenceError: token is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hello\djs-base-handler\index.js:16:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Comment: Well where do you define token?

Comment: 1) Make sure your config.json file is *right next* to your index.js in terms of directory. 2) Your error states token is undefined, yet you use `client.config.token` in your code. Which one have you tried, or have both of these failed?

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you get your token from your json, try this instead :

```js
//assuming the file is on the root of your project, else put the full path
const { token } = require('./config.json')
//...
client.login(token)
```

Comment: The OP's attempt is valid on the surface. `require("./config.json")` returns the object which is what is assigned to `client.config`